# API REST php7 symfony 3.4 - Databind json to forms

Tags: php, json, symfony, symfony-forms, databinder

I found this: ["How to process nested json with FOSRestBundle and Symfony forms"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690274/how-to-process-nested-json-with-fosrestbundle-and-symfony-forms) but the acepted reply was: ["making an unmapped form and binding data manually using a form event"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34690877/2423216)

In [play](https://www.playframework.com), you can write [your own data binder](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaForms#Register-a-custom-DataBinder) but for most formats(`xml`, `json`, ...), you can take the data automatically based on the `Content-Type` http header (the `@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)` is not mandatory [here](https://github.com/denisacostaq/FullStackPlayRestFullAngularJS/blob/master/app/controllers/api/Product.java#L28) to get it working), there are some well know data binders available(from Spring or wherever). [A product can have a list of items](https://github.com/denisacostaq/FullStackPlayRestFullAngularJS/blob/master/app/models/Product.java#L44), and even so, [you can bind the request body to a form automatically](https://github.com/denisacostaq/FullStackPlayRestFullAngularJS/blob/master/app/controllers/api/Product.java#L30).

PHP/Symfony no learn yet how to solve this issue?
If I create an API REST in php + symfonmy I need to write some kind of "parser" like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34690877/2423216)?
Can some one share a link to a post or an example with a solution to this?

PD: I use the play example because I am not an experienced web developer(less in PHP), so take this like my mcve.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue be sure all field on the form that have a relation are defined explicit:

```
$builder->add('field_simple')
        ->add('field_entity')
...
```

The code above will not work because the field 'field_entity' will be take like another simple field, you will have to define all the fields of entities or at lest the fields of interest, example:

```
$builder->add('field_simple')
        ->add('field_entity', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => CustomEntity::class,
            ...
        ))
...
```

Best Regards...

Answer (score 0):

By my experience you can achieve this by two ways:

1. Deserializing the JSON into a entity
2. Handling the request with a form as you suggest

In my projects I always do it with the second method because it to much easy to update the entities from a database loaded entity and handle the validation of your data.

I let you a link that is in a old version but remain more or less the same [knp university](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-rest/form-post)

I hope this can help you

Comment: I tried this, but not work when I have a [nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690274/how-to-process-nested-json-with-fosrestbundle-and-symfony-forms) :(.

Comment: I suppose that was related entities, you can achieve it with the collection type, I can do with this kind of forms, https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html